# Modifying Export to Excel in ReportViewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer, reportviewer2008

I have a formatted table in ReportViewer. When I want to export to Excel though - I do not want to export the formatted table - instead I want to output the original/raw/unmassaged data table in an excel file.

What's the best way to intercept the Export to Excel function and output data in a different format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `ShowExportButton` to `False` in the ReportViewer and add a new button in your page that do the work.

Or you can get into the `ReportExport` event, set the Cancel to `True`, and the fire your custom method.

```
Private Sub ReportViewer1_ReportExport(ByVal sender As Object, _
           ByVal e As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportExportEventArgs) _
           Handles ReportViewer1.ReportExport
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: hmm, I guess that's a start... is there anyway I could modify/intercept the Export to Excel command before it gets called?

Comment: Take a look at the ´ReportExport´ event. I haven't tested it, but it seems to have all what you need.

Comment: @firedrawndagger - Did you have luck implementing it? I am looking to remove formatting from Excel and save it as raw data. Your help is much appreciated!